# route drawing using google api not working in objc

Tags: dictionary, routes

i was using http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@ api for the step based route plotting . Till the last week i got the response in correct manner . But now the response is only null . Can anyone faced the same issue . Apple map is not plotting correctly in india . when we plot google map/direction api the step is not proper in MKMapkit. Is there any other way to have an accurate map  in ObjectiveC

my code is below

```
 NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
        NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

        NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
        NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];
        NSLog(@"api url: %@", apiUrl);
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",apiResponse);
```